# Server-side programming: PHP vs GWT+RPC

Tags: php, gwt-rpc, server-side

I am trying to develop a webpage which will need to create files in server-side with the text that a user writes in a textarea.

Which technology do you suggest me to use for this purpose? PHP or GWT+RCP?
I would like to use the easier to develop, more secure and faster one.

THANKS

Comment: will u be deploying this on a public shared hosting service?

Comment: Probably on Google App Engine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security issues in most toolkits stem from developer misunderstandings and errors.  So I would say that for most toolkits, your code will be as secure as you make it.

That said, this sounds like a task for PHP.  It's very simple and straightforward, and PHP is very good at that.

I can't speak for performance, but if that's very critical to you, then you could use eAccelerator to cache the compiled form of PHP scripts to eliminate the parsing step.  But from your description it doesn't sound like performance is going to be a huge deal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally betting that PHP is simpler and better for the problem at-hand.
file_put_contents() specifically, but you can also fopen/fputs/fclose for better management.

Comment: Just in case I would need to store this application on Google App Engine, I guess PHP is not a solution, right? Thanks a lot all of you.

Comment: Given your options are java and python, I would tend to agree that PHP is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see myself as a big fan of PHP, but it seems the be the better choice. PHP is easy enough for small projects like this one. GWT is better for web applications (compared to websites).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is the better one for that purpose, a simple web site. GWT is nice for building RIA's but too big and complex for this. If you need some AJAX issues, or if you want to make nice javascript effects, you can use jQuery or something similar in addition to your PHP code.